# Convert Locator (x,y) values to Lat/Lon as per GetCoordinates on Map

Tags: coordinate-transformation, geodesy

I want to convert the (x,y) coordinates you get from using a locator on a map to Lat/Lon coordinates - exactly like the GetCoordinates tool does when you right click on a map.

```
Manipulate[GeoGraphics[GeoPosition[{51.5164090, -0.0943590}],
GeoRange -> Quantity[0.20, "Miles"]], {u, Locator}, {u}]
```

ie if I create a simple map and use use right click -> GetCoordinates it will give me 3 pairs of values

1. Lat Lon
2. Lat Lon in degrees
3. (x,y)  <--  this is the one Locator returns.

Simple demo map

```
GeoGraphics[GeoPosition[{51.5164090, -0.0943590}], 
GeoRange -> Quantity[10, "Miles"]]
```

Im presuming its related to GeoPositionENU somehow but the starting point seems to change for each instance of the map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you examine the AbsoluteOptions for the GeoGraphics you can see what is used by the Get Coordinates tool: [`CoordinatesToolOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinatesToolOptions.html).

```
g = GeoGraphics[GeoPosition[{51.5164090, -0.0943590}], 
  GeoRange -> Quantity[0.20, "Miles"], ImageSize -> 600];

CoordinatesToolOptions/.AbsoluteOptions[g]
(* {DisplayFunction->
    (GeoGraphics`GeoGridPositionDisplay[
      #1,{Mercator,Centering->GeoPosition[{51.5164,-0.094359}],GridOrigin->{-0.094359,0}},ITRF00
                                        ]&),
    CopiedValueFunction->
    (GeoGraphics`GeoGridPositionCopiedValue[
      #1,{Mercator,Centering->GeoPosition[{51.5164,-0.094359}],GridOrigin->{-0.094359,0}},ITRF00
                                        ]&)} *)
```

Pull out the "DisplayFunction" and use that function:

```
tr = "DisplayFunction" /. (CoordinatesToolOptions /. AbsoluteOptions[g]);
```

Here I define function that takes care of the Automatic case.

```
trans[u_] := tr[u]
trans[Automatic] = tr[Mean /@ (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g])];
```

Now:

```
Manipulate[Column[{Style[trans[u], {16, "Text"}], g}], {u, Locator}]
```

[image]